# Indigenous sites, museums or cultural centers along the road between Albuquerque and Moab?

Tags: museums, utah, arizona, indigenous-peoples, new-mexico

I will be travelling in the U.S. with my family in April. We will travel by car from Texas to Utah, most likely via Albuquerque.

We would like to visit an Indigenous site, museum or cultural center during our trip. I know this is a broad category, but essentially we'd like to visit a place which could tell us a bit about Native Americans.

We're travelling with children (~10 years), so it should be a place which will appeal to them as well.

I see that there's quite a few reservations along the road between Albuquerque and Moab (NW in New Mexico, NE in Arizona or SE in Utah). We'll plan our route according to the stops we'd like to make.

Are there any such sites, museums or cultural centers visiting between Albuquerque and Moab?

Comment: Facetiously, the answer your question is "yes", because there are many such sites.  However, as it stands your question is unanswerable because we can't know what you consider "worthwhile".  I'd also suggest that you read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and pay attention to the "not" part.

Comment: @PeterM yes, the question could probably qualify as a "not" question. I have removed the "worth" in "worth visiting" to make the question less subjective or opinion based. What I could be hoping for was first hand knowledge from someone who lives in that area or knows that area.

Comment: I live in the area, and I still can't tell what you might want to see, because only you can do that.  In addition, your question would cover everything from ruins, to petroglyphs, to badlands, to sacred mountains, to actual museums - so the shear volume of locations makes it hard to answer.

Comment: @PeterM alright, I do understand your point - although I was expecting (and hoping for) a broad range of suggestions. Anyway, do you suggest that i clarify the question more or just delete it?

Comment: The easiest way to get a broad range of suggestions is to use google to look for national parks, national monuments, national heritage sites and indigenous museums - this will give you the well known highlights.  From there you can decide what sites are near your potential travel routes, and are suitable for your type of vehicle.  Once you have that list, then a reasonable question would be are particular sites suitable for children. But still, you know your own children and whether they would prefer a  museum of native arts over walking through historic ruins.